# I need to modify this shell script to match the parameters in between the two specified by user

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I have this script and i need to modify it so that there are 2 inputs from the user. Then i need the script to return a list of numbers that are between the two.
The list of parameters is 5 10 6 12 5 18 10 4 19 21 5 12 18 22 For example: if the user inputs 12 and 20 we would have 5 matches (12, 18, 19, 12, 18).

```
#!/bin/bash 
read –p “Enter the number you seek  “ NUM 
for VALUE in $@; do 
if [ $VALUE –eq $NUM ]; then COUNT=$((COUNT+1)); fi 
Done 
echo $NUM appeared $COUNT times
```

I know how to add the second user input i am just stuck on how to get it to return the numbers in between.

Comment: Your example reads only one variable `NUM` but you say that you expect the user to input two numbers (say 12 and 20). You should either ask the user to enter both numbers on the same line `read –p “Enter TWO numbers that you seek  “ NUM1 NUM2`. Or ask twice in a row `read –p “Enter the first number you seek  “ NUM1; read –p “Enter the second number you seek  “ NUM2`. (I prefer the latter)

Comment: Also, you're using "smart" quotes, `““`, instead of straight quotes, `""` – Bash treats the former as normal characters and will be confused.

Answer (score 0):

This will do :

```
#!/bin/bash

printf "Enter the number you seek : "
read  NUM 
printf "Enter the second number you seek : "
read NUM2

echo "$@" | tr ' ' '\n' | sort -nr | awk -v "num=$NUM" -v "num2=$NUM2" '$1 >= num && $1 <= num2'
```

Let me know if it helps!

Comment: The fugly `echo | tr` could elegantly be replaced with `printf '%s\n' "$@"`

Comment: Also `read -p` is probably better than `printf` + `read` (though probably also add `-r`).